# Shell script: Simple compare in brackets not working the way I expect?

Tags: shell, sh, esxi

I am attempting to write a script to return the size, in bytes, of a disk. So far so good. I then want to display that in as human-readable of units as I can, without attempting to display a small size in millionths of a TB nor a terrabytes value in bytes. So if the number of bytes is above 1024 try KB, if that number is above 1024 try MB, etc. For illustration purposes my actual value is 10632563023872.

Everyone says to use double brackets where possible. Most of my script is written with double brackets. But in this case the math is simply not working the way I expect it to, so maybe someone can help me to understand what I'm missing. The entire script has a lot more to it, but I've managed to isolate my problem into one line:

```
num=10632563023872; 
if [[ $num -lt 1024 ]]; 
then echo "$num is less than 1024"; 
else echo "$num is greater than 1024"; 
fi
```

Output:

```
10632563023872 is less than 1024
```

Although shellcheck says the syntax is fine, the math is obviously(?) wrong unless there's some sort of datatype issue I'm missing, but there's no declaring variables and datatypes in bash. If I try this with parentheses I get the right answer, although there is an error thrown which I've confirmed means it's just returning false because it doesn't like my input:

```
num=10632563023872; 
if (( $num -lt 1024 )); 
then echo "$num is less than 1024"; 
else echo "$num is greater than 1024"; 
fi
```

```
-sh: 10632563023872: not found
10632563023872 is greater than 1024
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209970/discussion-on-question-by-lee-crawford-shell-script-simple-compare-in-brackets).

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Why does the bracketed code not work the way I expect?

**A:** Because it turns out ESXi CLI environment is not bash, even though the syntax I've used is generally bash-flavored. In asking this question I have learned that it's not bash so any differences from bash are just artifacts of this not being a true bash environment.

**Q:** What syntax would accomplish the task better than `[[ $num -lt 1024 ]]` in my situation?

**A:** `[[ $num \> 1024 ]]` seems to work reliably.  That said, "if in a shell where [[ acts like [, [[ $num > 1024 ]] is doing a string comparison instead of a numeric comparison. If it fixes your problem, that implies that $num isn't actually a valid number -- maybe it's being read from a file or other source that has DOS newlines instead of UNIX ones, just to throw out a potential cause at random?"

I originally tagged the question as bash, but when it became apparent that ESXi doesn't strictly use a recognizable version of bash shell, I changed the tag to ESXi. For future readers, I hope this helps explain why some code may not work "like it's supposed to" when writing ESXi scripts.

Thank you to the people who offered direction in comments.